# Nickel(II) acetylacetonate crystals coming out blue

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, synthesis

An experiment in my class has us synthesising the acetylacetonate complex from hydrated nickel chloride being added to a solution of ammonia, acetylacetone and water. The products came out pale blue, yet according to every source I can find, the crystals should be green. Just wondering what the structure would be to accomodate the colour.

Comment: What do you mean by "the product**s**"? Were there more than one type of crystals, or are you referring to the mother liquor and crystals? It would also be beneficial if you could add some information regarding the amounts of reactants used for the synthesis as well as upload the photo(s)—the *dihydrate* is a borderline case being greenish-blue.

Comment: Wikipedia states that the anhydrous Nickel(II) acetylacetonate is green. But the dehydrated compound is blue.

Answer (score 2):

You obtained the dihydrate complex of AAN. If you want to obtain green crystals, you should use azeotropic evaporation to remove crystal water. Then you will have green product - anhydrous AAN.